# Finding Parts of File Names and comparing them

Tags: java

Hello all I am okay with java but not an expert I have been tasked with doing the following: (1) search before and after files to compare, use the first two (2) sections of the filename, company code and description.

The program below I have modified to fit my needs which searches both folders for file names that contain words or letter this works. **the problem is that I want this program to compare file name parts. ***

(1) search for the file name parts the contain only **Company code and description** and omit the rest (because the files stored in the before and after folders will be slightly different). I want to do this for all files in both folders **and hold the ones that match in an array** Then Print them out (printing them out i know how to do that).

(Below step optional pretty but concerned with the 1st step)
(2) I want to take information stored in both arrays and compare the data inside the file to see if it is the same.

**Folder A = 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200259-CD61C4.txt**
**Folder B = 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200259-CD61C4-LABEL.txt**
***I am trying to parse out -2017200259-CD61C4 in both the text file***

```
public class NameOne {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File FolderA = new File("C:/Users/hoflerj/Desktop/FolderA");
    File [] filesOne = FolderA.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File FolderA, String nameOne) {
            //return name.endsWith(".txt");
            return nameOne.contains("test");
        }
    });


    for (File txtfile : filesOne) {
       if ( txtfile.getName().contains("t")){
            System.out.println("Match found ---> " + (txtfile));
            //System.out.println(txtfile);
       }
            else{

                System.out.println("(FolderA) not contain specified match");

            }
        }

    System.out.println("\n");

    File FolderB = new File("C:/Users/hoflerj/Desktop/FolderB");
    File [] filesTwo = FolderB.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File FolderB, String nameTwo) {
            //return name.endsWith(".txt");
            return nameTwo.contains("test");
        }
    });

    for (File txtfile : filesTwo) {
           if ( txtfile.getName().contains("t")){
                System.out.println("Match found ---> " + (txtfile));
           }
                else{
                    System.out.println("(FolderB) not contain specified match");

                }
            }



    }   

}
```

Comment: Well from your description `contains` seems to do the trick.  Give an example of the filenames and what parts you are trying to parse out.  That would help.

Comment: Folder A =  3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200259-CD61C4.txt
Folder B =  3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200259-CD61C4-LABEL.txt

Comment: This is an example there will be variations of this

Comment: This section I am trying to parse out - SUIQUARTER2-2017200259-CD61C4.txt

Comment: Does your question boil down to how do I filter `Company code and description`  out of a given file name ?  Is this `SUIQUARTER2-2017200259-CD61C4` an example of a company code and description ?